React-native geolocation api, Heading is always Zero. Unable to show realtime accuarate movement (android)
Its shocking that react-native-geolocation package is unable to show the real-time heading of an android device despite the lat and lng are updated in real-time and the device moves. I refrain from using onLocationChange which is built into google maps it self because it will put a blue circular icon which I have not way of getting around that. I prefer to use my own marker icon. I have followed the instruction on the github page and still the heading does not update. I resulted to use the sensors on the device only to use my two devices and they all don't have magnetometer. I have to gracefully exit and handle if the device has no magnetometer. I tried to go around using gyroscope but my devices don't have that either. I was shocked part two, because there are hardware modules available for a long time. I am back at fixing geolocation or if there is a way of removing the blue icon that comes with onLocationChange. Regardless examine my code and see if there are any gaps.
//track patrol team location
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization(
      (_success?: any) => {
        console.log("Location permission requested successfully");
      },
      (error?: GeolocationError) => {
        console.log("Error requesting location permission:", error);
      }
    );
    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude, heading: geoHeading } = position.coords;
        setCurrentPosition({
          coordinate: { latitude, longitude },
          altitude: position.coords.altitude ?? 0,
          accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
          speed: position.coords.speed ?? 0,
          heading: (heading || geoHeading) ?? 0, // Use heading if available
          altitudeAccuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy ?? undefined,
          timeStamp: position.timestamp,
        });

        if (origin && destination && recordingMode) {
          if (
            state &&
            state.location.lat !== latitude &&
            state.location.lng !== longitude
          ) {
            dispatch({
              type: Types.SetLocation,
              payload: {
                lat: latitude ?? 0,
                lng: longitude ?? 0,
                heading: heading ?? 0,
              },
            });
          } else return;
          makeLogEntry({
            latitude,
            longitude,
            heading: heading ?? undefined,
          })
            .then(() => console.log("Log made successfully"))
            .catch((error) => console.log("Error making log entry:", error));
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("Error watching position:", error);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        interval: 5000,
        fastestInterval: 2000,
      }
    );

    return () => {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
    };
  }, [origin, destination, recordingMode]);


According to my knowledge, position.coords.heading is not reliable on android in some cases, as it typically reports heading if the device is moving with speed of atleast 5m per second.
So, You should calculate heading based on movement rather than relying on device heading, as it might not heading in certain cases. Use a callback function when heading is unavailable or unrelyable.
const calculateBearing = (lat1: number, lon1: number, lat2: number, lon2: number) => {
  const toRadians = (degree: number) => (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
  const y = Math.sin(lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  const x =
    Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) -
    Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1);
  const bearing = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180) / Math.PI;
  return (bearing + 360) % 360; // Normalize bearing to 0-360 degrees
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  Geolocation.requestAuthorization();

  if (!origin && !destination && !recordingMode) {
    if (watchId !== null) {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
      setWatchId(null);
    }

    const noSaveWatchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude, speed, heading: geoHeading } = position.coords;
        
        const fallbackHeading = calculateBearing(
          prevLatitude, prevLongitude,
          latitude, longitude
        ); // Calculate heading from the previous and current coordinates

        setCurrentPosition({
          coordinate: { latitude, longitude },
          speed: speed as number,
          heading: geoHeading || fallbackHeading,
        });

        // Update prevLatitude and prevLongitude to the current location
        prevLatitude = latitude;
        prevLongitude = longitude;
      },
      (error) => console.error(error),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        interval: 5000,
        fastestInterval: 2000,
      }
    );

    setWatchId(noSaveWatchId);

    return () => {
      if (noSaveWatchId !== null) {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(noSaveWatchId);
      }
    };
  } else if (origin && destination && recordingMode) {
    // Same approach here for `saveWatchId`
  }
}, [origin, destination, recordingMode]);

Try this out and let me know if it solves your problem.
2nd
You said that you are not using onLocationChange because it puts a blue circle, so i am assuming you are using react-native-maps for the map. You can disable the blue dot by doing this.
<MapView
  showsUserLocation={false}  // Disables the blue dot
  followsUserLocation={false} // Prevents camera from following user
  // Other map properties
>
  //custom marker 
  <Marker
    coordinate={currentPosition.coordinate}
    heading={currentPosition.heading}
    // Your custom icon or marker logic
  />
</MapView>


onLocationChange if I am wrong requires showUserLocation to function. Please confirm the second part again

You can always use a custom marker and set it to current location by fetching coordinates to show user location. showUserLocation is to show the default google blue dot to show current location, which you do not want to show
